# Prove that $pq - q - p +1 = 0$ have no solutions under given conditions.

Tags: inequality

Let's say I have the an equation:
$p,q \in N-\{0\}$, $p,q \ge 2 : pq - q - p +1= 0$
I want to show that there is no such p and q for that equation. Please help.

Comment: Hint: you can try to factor the expression $pq - p - q + 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have: $pq-p-q+1=0\implies (p-1)(q-1)=0$.

But you are given that $p,q\ge2$ and $p,q \in N-\{0\}$.

Can you take it from here??

Comment: yeah, thanks much appriciated.

Comment: @Itay.V, Always Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the factorization:

**Idea:** exploit the size of $pq$ to make up for the $-p$ and $-q$.
Naive first thought: $pq\geq2q$, so $pq-p-q+1\geq q-p+1$. However, $q-p$ is uncontrollable.
Refined idea: Divide and conquer: split the size of $pq$ over the two negative terms:
$$pq=\frac12pq+\frac12pq\geq\frac122p+\frac122q=p+q$$
and we're done.