# Inequality proof, (pq)^2 - 8pq + 4p + 4q - 1 = 0

Tags: inequality

i've asked some thing similar here ([question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052691/inequality-proof-pq-q-p-1-0/2052696?noredirect=1#comment4213390_2052696)) but i found out now that im looking for some thing abit different so  lets say i have the next equation:
$p,q \in N-\{0\}$, $p,q \ge 2 : (pq)^2 - 8pq + 4p + 4q - 1 = 0$
I want to show that there is now such p and q for that equation. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inequality proof, $pq - q - p +1 = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052691/inequality-proof-pq-q-p-1-0)

Comment: @amWhy
i just said that i've asked some thing similar, why you people dont even read ?? 
and where is it duplicate ? thats not even looks alike..

Comment: This is close enough to your earlier question where you needed to solve an equality for which $p, q \geq 2$. Duplicates can be duplicates in terms of exactly duplicated method used to solve each.

Comment: @amWhy it was 5 minutes ago and its not even slightly close

Comment: To the point: you can solve this question just as you (and your answerer solved for $p,q \ge 2 : pq - q - p +1= 0$

Comment: @amWhy It's a completely different expression. For one thing, I don't immediately see an easy factorisation. At the very least, it's different enough not to warrant a close-by-duplicate in my opinion.

Comment: My point is also that Itay has failed to show any work in their questions.  Asking for an answer to the same kind of question, and expecting to have hand held every step of the solution is not what this site is meant for.  @Arthur, this site is not about repeatedly proving $x^2-9= (x-3)(x+3)$, and that $x^2-16= (x-4)(x+4),$ etc (which are completely different expressions, after all!) for the sake of one user who fails to provide any of their own work.

Comment: @amWhy I'm not disputing that it's low quality. But please, $x^2-9$ is the same expression as $x^2-16$ under the very simple variable substitution $3\mapsto4$, while no substitution that simple lets you transform $pq-p-q+1$ to $(pq)^2-8pq+4p+4q-1$.

Comment: Give it up, once and for all, okay, @Arthur ?  When I refer to the post as "low quality", I don't mean what "level" (easy hard or inbetween), I am referring to the OPs continued  disregard for comments, suggestions, questions. We clearly disagree about what constitutes a duplicate.  Period.

Comment: @amWhy I'd say it's duplicate when a full answer to one question provides a full answer to the other, or something along those lines. What do you think is a duplicate? This question is low quality, clearly. Most importantly because of the lack of the OP's own work. If you had said that, I would've agreed wholeheartedly. I think you voted to close this question on the wrong grounds, and I take issue with that. Either you are wrong, or I am, and no matter which one it is, clearing it up will help us both make this site a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given equation, written under the form

$$\tag{0}p^2 q^2 - 4 p (2q -1) + (4q - 1)=0$$

can be considered as quadratic (under the provision that $q \neq 0$) in variable $p$, with $q$ seen as a parameter .

Its solutions are

$$\tag{1}p=\frac{-2 + 4\,q \pm \sqrt{\Delta(q)}}
   {q^2} \ \ \text{with discriminant } \ \ \Delta(q)=4 - 16\,q + 17\,q^2 - 4\,q^3.$$

We aim at finding positive integer solutions for $p \geq 0$ and $q > 0$.

In particular, a first constraint is that these solutions must be real. Thus $\Delta(q)>0$. A short study of function $\Delta$ for $q>0$ (see graphics below) shows that $\Delta(q)>0$ for $q=1,2,3$ for which $\sqrt{\Delta(q)}=1,2\sqrt{2},1$. Plugging these values of $\sqrt{\Delta(q)}$ in $(1)$ gives integer values only if $q=1$ (and thus $p=1$), or $q=3$ (and thus $p=1$ again).

The case $q=0$ has to be treated in a separate way by considering equation $(0)$, giving non-integer solution: $p=1/4$.

> It remains only integer solutions $(p,q)=(1,1), (1,3)$ and, taking into account the symmetry of the initial equation in variables $(p,q)$, a third solution $(p,q)=(3,1).$

The curve of function $\Delta:$

[image]

Comment: Don't think I could get better answer, thanks!!